# Получить разницу между двумя объектами `datetime` в часах

Tags: python, datetime

Есть datetime регистрации пользователя такого вида `2018-10-31 16:44:20` (строка)
И есть например вторая дата `2018-11-31 7:14:01` (строка)

Как можно узнать сколько прошло часов от первой даты до второй?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime as DT

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

hrs = ((DT.strptime('2018-10-31 16:44:20', fmt) - DT.strptime('2018-10-31 7:14:01', fmt))
       .total_seconds() / 3600)

print(hrs)
# 9.505277777777778
```